# Undefined variable: _get in

Tags: php

I get the following error:

> Undefined variable: _get in ... 
>   this is the part of the code that is causing it:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/config.php");
//

require('C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\vendor\setasign\fpdf\fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$search=isset($_REQUEST['search']) ? $_REQUEST['search']:'';
$option=isset($_REQUEST['option']) ? $_REQUEST['option']:'';
$period=isset($_REQUEST['period']) ? $_REQUEST['period']:'';
$datefrom=isset($_REQUEST['datefrom']) ? $_REQUEST['datefrom']:'';
$dateto=isset($_REQUEST['dateto']) ? $_REQUEST['dateto']:'';

if($period ==null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfacility JOIN tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where ".$search." ='".$option."' ";}
else{
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblfacility JOIN tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where ".$search." ='".$option."' AND time between '".$datefrom."' and '".$dateto."' ";
}
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{

foreach($results as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$column,1);
} }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It is giving a blank output.FIle problem may be with variable option and search .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: That code looks pretty bad - have you defined all these constants you are accessing?

Comment: If an answer solved your question and you get a new error, you  should not change the content of  your question.

Answer (score 3):

The global variable `$_GET` is only in uppercase. So you have to change

```
$search=$_get[search];
```

to

```
$search=$_GET['search'];
```

Comment: iT is not working still the error  Warning: Use of undefined constant search - assumed 'search' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\library\admin\genratepdf.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\library\admin\genratepdf.php on line 23

Comment: @dev yes you have to put `search` in quotes. Like this: `'search' `

Comment: @dev same for the other key that you use in `$_POST`

Comment: still it shows error  Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\library\admin\genratepdf.php on line 23

Comment: Have u changed that code.I am new to this forum Just asking

Comment: @dev @dev maybe its better if you search for a basic tutorial how to handle post get variables with php, or google the error messages itself. `Undefined index: search in ...` means that there was no input with name `search` send by the get request. Yes I changed the code because it was unrelated to the error message. Your question is about basic GET request in PHP and its not relevant that you are using FPDF. If you ask questions here in future, please make sure to provide a minimal example instead of large pieces of code that are unrelated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202256/discussion-between-dev-and-adam).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$search=isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search']:'';
```

or

```
$search=isset($_REQUEST['search']) ? $_REQUEST['search']:'';
```

Comment: We now have the null-coalescing operator. There is no need for this.

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer? How does it solve the given error? Please note that the error message was not about any undefined indices within an array

Comment: @NicoHaase this solution could not solve the problem.Please help

Comment: @NicoHaase Is there any way to transfer the variable to the third page

Comment: What do you mean by that? There is no "third page" in your question. And if you have additional details about the problem, please edit your question to contain all information. Don't put such stuff in the comment section

Comment: @selvan It gives a blank page output

Comment: add the below two lines in the top of the page.  error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);
 ini_set("display_errors","on");

Comment: @selvan nothing happened

Comment: @selvan Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\vendor\setasign\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\vendor\setasign\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\vendor\setasign\fpdf\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\library\admin\genratepdf.php(53): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\geochronology\vendor\setasign\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: Please remove If any unwanted white space or html content in the page. So that the header will load the pdf document.